# Titanium appcelerator image view load event listener not working with android

Tags: android, imageview, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile, event-listener

i have an image view, when the image loads i want to make an action, for example an alert.I'm using eventListener method to implement this.
here's my code

```
imageView.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    alert(1);
});
```

this workd fine with iphone, but not firing anything with android,
how can achieve this within android?
thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Appcelerator has not resolved this issue in Titanium Mobile quite yet, however the following [workaround](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117356/imageview-load-event-not-firing-on-iphone) may be used for both remote and local images to achieve your desired result.